# recursive UDF inaccurate in SSRS with embedded SQL

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, user-defined-functions

I am creating a report in Report Designer.  The dataset uses a query that looks like:

```
SELECT LE.Amount, dbo.fnMoneyToEnglish(LE.Amount)
FROM tblXXX LE
WHERE LE.ID = @ID
```

The UDF fnMoneyToEnglish should return words like:

> Thirty and 00/100 Dollars

but instead returns only

> Thirty

I suspect this is because the UDF uses recursion, calling itself.  When I execute the embedded SQL in a SQL query window the UDF returns the full "Thirty and 00/100 Dollars".  It's only Report Designer that has trouble, returning just "Thirty".  I find this odd because I would expect SSRS to make one call to the database, the UDF would execute and recurse.

Does Report Designer somehow decompose the query and is it limited to one call to the database?

FYI, here is the UDF:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnMoneyToEnglish](@Money AS Money) 

RETURNS VARCHAR(1024)

AS

BEGIN
 DECLARE @Number as BIGINT
 DECLARE @MinusFlag as Bit

if @Money < 0
 begin
 set @Money = -1 * @Money
 Set @MinusFlag = 1
 end

SET @Number = FLOOR(@Money)

DECLARE @Below20 TABLE (ID int identity(0,1), Word varchar(32))

DECLARE @Below100 TABLE (ID int identity(2,1), Word varchar(32))

INSERT into @Below20 (Word) VALUES ( 'Zero')
 INSERT into @Below20 (Word) VALUES ('One')
 INSERT into @Below20 (Word) VALUES ('Two')
 INSERT into @Below20 (Word) VALUES ('Three')
 INSERT into @Below20 (Word) VALUES ('Four')
 INSERT into @Below20 (Word) VALUES ('Five')
 INSERT into @Below20 (Word) VALUES ('Six')
 INSERT into @Below20 (Word) VALUES ('Seven')
 INSERT into @Below20 (Word) VALUES ('Eight')
 INSERT into @Below20 (Word) VALUES ('Nine')
 INSERT into @Below20 (Word) VALUES ('Ten')
 INSERT into @Below20 (Word) VALUES ('Eleven')
 INSERT into @Below20 (Word) VALUES ('Twelve')
 INSERT into @Below20 (Word) VALUES ('Thirteen')
 INSERT into @Below20 (Word) VALUES ('Fourteen')
 INSERT into @Below20 (Word) VALUES ('Fifteen')
 INSERT into @Below20 (Word) VALUES ('Sixteen')
 INSERT into @Below20 (Word) VALUES ('Seventeen')
 INSERT into @Below20 (Word) VALUES ('Eighteen')
 INSERT into @Below20 (Word) VALUES ('Nineteen') 

INSERT into @Below100 (Word) VALUES ('Twenty')
 INSERT into @Below100 (Word) VALUES ('Thirty')
 INSERT into @Below100 (Word) VALUES ('Forty')
 INSERT into @Below100 (Word) VALUES ('Fifty')
 INSERT into @Below100 (Word) VALUES ('Sixty')
 INSERT into @Below100 (Word) VALUES ('Seventy')
 INSERT into @Below100 (Word) VALUES ('Eighty')
 INSERT into @Below100 (Word) VALUES ('Ninety') 

DECLARE @English varchar(1024)
 (
 SELECT @English =
 Case 

WHEN @Number = 0 THEN ''

WHEN @Number BETWEEN 1 AND 19 

THEN (SELECT Word FROM @Below20 WHERE ID=@Number)

WHEN @Number BETWEEN 20 AND 99

-- SQL Server recursive function 

THEN (SELECT Word FROM @Below100 WHERE ID=@Number/10)+ '-' +

dbo.fnMoneyToEnglish( @Number % 10) 

WHEN @Number BETWEEN 100 AND 999 

THEN (dbo.fnMoneyToEnglish( @Number / 100))+' Hundred '+

dbo.fnMoneyToEnglish( @Number % 100) 

WHEN @Number BETWEEN 1000 AND 999999 

THEN (dbo.fnMoneyToEnglish( @Number / 1000))+' Thousand '+

dbo.fnMoneyToEnglish( @Number % 1000) 

WHEN @Number BETWEEN 1000000 AND 999999999 

THEN (dbo.fnMoneyToEnglish( @Number / 1000000))+' Million '+

dbo.fnMoneyToEnglish( @Number % 1000000) 

WHEN @Number BETWEEN 1000000000 AND 999999999999 

THEN (dbo.fnMoneyToEnglish( @Number / 1000000000))+' Billion '+

dbo.fnMoneyToEnglish( @Number % 1000000000) 

ELSE ' INVALID INPUT' END

)

SELECT @English = RTRIM(@English)

SELECT @English = RTRIM(LEFT(@English,len(@English)-1))

WHERE RIGHT(@English,1)='-'

IF @@NestLevel = 1

BEGIN

SELECT @English = @English+' and '
SELECT @English = @English+
    convert(varchar, RIGHT('00'+ convert(varchar, convert(int,100*(@Money - @Number))),2)) +'/100 Dollars'
 if (@MinusFlag = 1)
 begin
 set @English = '( ' + @English + ' )'
 end

END

RETURN (@English)

END
```

Comment: Does the Report Designer have a field width that is too small to accomodate the entire string?

Comment: Doesn't really answer your specific issue, but as a workaround would it be possible to wrap the function in a stored procedure that can then be called by the report? That might prevent these issues. Not always possible depending on what access you have of course.

Comment: Good thought but that's not an option here.

Comment: I just tested a copy of that UDF and was able to display the value "Thirty and 00/100 Dollars" in a textbox on a 2008 R2 report. I think you must have a problem with your report layout, have you tested making the textbox or table column wider?